# Reg. Tenant Law in Canada

Tags: canada, rental-property

We were in an apartment in Canada for two years. Unfortunately, due to my visa status, I had to leave the apartment in a very short notice (1 month).
The landlord agreed to use my caution deposit to clean the apartment and give me the remaining. Hence, after leaving Canada I requested him to give the bill and the remaining amount. This is when I received a threatening mail from his partner, that they were disgusted by the state of our apartment. He is threatening to sue us... He claims that we have destroyed the apartment... but the only problem we are aware of is that we left some of clothes in the apartment (our intention was to donate them and was hoping to request our landlord to do it on our behalf), as we couldn't trash them in the last minute (the garbage bins they gave was full and it is not possible for us to put them in a public bin). Other than that the only issue we were aware of is that handle in the refrigerator with a worn out thread. It was a recurring issue, which was "fixed" once by the landlord.

Honestly, if have had a few more days, we would have tried to leave the apartment in a better state. Cleaning was especially difficult with a crawler on tow and the landlords visiting our place as often as possible to show it to other potential clients.

Now we have left Canada and he is threatening us. Has anyone been in such a position? Could anyone advise me?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Advise you on what exactly? Your landlord is probably just pulling the typical move that slumlords do and is claiming that you did damage etc so that he can keep your damage deposit. He legally has to pay you interest on your last month's rent deposit. Tell him to pay you what he owes you by law before he wants to start talking about possibly suing you.

Comment: Also, no offense to Americans here, but in Canada we don't have a litigious culture like they do. All he'd be able to get out of you maximum are actual damages that he can prove were caused by you, and that would be difficult. He'd need to have plenty of proof from an independent third party of inspection just prior to your move-in date and then also the same thing just after you moved out. Unless you really did mash up the place, he's talking smack to get out of having to pay you back your deposit.